# Ffmpeg Video Codec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I split video like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:15:00 -t 00:15:00 -i life.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy life-2.mp4
```

After the process i want to play splitted file on flash player (JW Player), it doesnt starts. It waits to download all af video and then start. But the source video (life.mp4) starts playing immediately. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use qt-faststart, which comes with FFmpeg, or MP4Box, which is part of GPAC, or any other similar tool. It will move some data to the beginning of the output file so it can begin playing before being completely downloaded. If qt-faststart is not available to you then you can get the [FFmpeg source](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and easily compile it:

```
cd ffmpeg/tools
make qt-faststart
```

Then use it like this:

```
qt-faststart input.mp4 output.mp4
```

Also, I recommend using `-ss` as an output option. It will be slower, but will often be more accurate.

Comment: Outdated. Use `-movflags +faststart` in ffmpeg instead.